# The instruction ThisWorkbook.Activate is not working

Tags: excel, vba

I have two workbooks. In the first one, I call a macro that activate the other one and take several data from there. Then it opens an UserForm, where it runs a macro in the OK button click. In this moment, the function ThisWorkbook.Activate doesn't work. The ActiveWorkbook.Name remains the other one. But when the macro stops, the Activeworkbook turn correct. Why this can happen. (I didn't have this problem in older Excel Version I had)

I tried to change screenupdating. I tried to wait a time before and after activate.  I tried to unprotect sheet. I have no idea of what to do.

```
Private Sub btOK_Click()    
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True    
    Me.Hide    
    Plan_Inser_Ativ = ValorVariavel("Plan_Inser_Ativ") 'Function to Take a recorded text of Sheet Name (This is working)    
    ThisWorkbook.Unprotect    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Plan_Inser_Ativ).Activate 'I tried to activate the workbook by this method, but this is not working    
    ThisWorkbook.Activate 'I tried to activate by this other method, but this is not working too    
    'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))    
    ThisWorkbook.Activate 'I tried to insist in it to see what happens :-)    
    WB_Ativa = ActiveWorkbook.Name 'The WB_Ativa variable remains with the other Workbook name.    
    Stop 'When the macro stops, if I place the mouse over the ActiveWorkbook.Name statement, it shows that the active Workbook is correct. But before the macro to stop, it was not.`
    ..    
    ..    
    ..
```

[image: Print Screen of Macro variable states]

Comment: `ThisWorkbook` is always going to be the workbook that contains the VBA code you're looking at.

Comment: Exactly. The problem is that wen I use "ThisWorkbook.Activate", it does not change the "ActiveWorkbook.Name" to the Workbook where the macro is programmed.

Comment: @LeandroTeixeira is there a reason why you wouldn't say `WB_Ativa = ThisWorkbook.Name` then?

Comment: The point is, `ThisWorkbook` is always the same workbook. Do you have a reference to "the other workbook" somewhere? Is it VBA code that's opening it, or the user? Is it always the same file name? If so, then you can do `Set theOtherBook = Workbooks("theOtherBook.xlsx")` and go `theOtherBook.Activate`.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ my understanding is that they have two workbooks opened, and they want to activate the one that isn't `ThisWorkbook`. Hard to answer this question without knowing anything about that other workbook other than, well, it's opened, and not active.

Comment: The other workbook is opened by other Sub and it is a variable. (Workbooks(Arq_Cronograma).Sheets("Tarefas").Activate) and it's working correcly.

Comment: Good. Then `Workbooks(Arq_Cronograma).Activate` should do what you need! Or is `Arq_Cronograma` out of scope?

Comment: Rather than using ThisWorkbook, which appears to be working as intended, why not use something such as Dim SrcWB as Workbook, DstWB as Workbook, Set each, and use those when qualifying?

Comment: @Cyril if one of the two workbooks involved is `ThisWorkbook`, IMO copying that reference to a variable is only going to make the code harder to follow. `ThisWorkbook` is unambiguously `ThisWorkbook`. I can stand behind `srcWb` and `dstWb` *parameters* for a procedure that performs operations across any two workbooks, but I would deem copying the object reference of `ThisWorkbook` to another variable, harmful.

Comment: The WB_Ativa variable is only a test line I put to see if the instruction ThisWorkbook.Activate is working. But this line shows that it's not working, because it remains in the other workbook.

Comment: Try taking everything you have after `Me.Hide`, and put that in whatever code is invoking the form.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. What version of Excel are you using, and can you please [edit] your question so that it contains a [mcve] that consistently reproduces the problem? There are too many unknowns here.

Comment: Add a `DoEvents`.  Judging by your screenshot, you've probably managed to deadlock it somewhere.

Comment: I put the code before the Userform.Show and it worked... I use this all over my program that is very big.. And this works everywhere. Only in this case of this OK button click that it's not working..

Comment: The OK button should do `Me.Hide` *and nothing else* though.

Comment: I'm using Office 365 ProPlus. Excel Version 1808(16.0.10730.20264) 64 bit. My older Excel where this program worked was 32 bits.

Comment: @LeandroTeixeira You're probably lucky that it worked at all - based on what it looks like you're trying to do (I'm *still* not entirely clear on that based on the question and comments), it seems pretty close to how I would demonstrate how to cause a deadlock.

Comment: DoEvents did not solve the problem